# Average score for a Quiz based on recent performance

Tags: algorithms, average, algorithmic-game-theory

A quiz always has 10 questions.
Correct answer results in 1 mark. No negative marking.

A user can take the quiz as many times as he likes.
I want to show his 'Average Score' based on last 5 quiz scores (irrespective of how many times he takes the quiz).

I do not want to store his individual scores per se, only the Average.

One way to do this:
Current Average Score: 3
Quiz Score: 8
New Average Score: (8+3)/2 = 5.5

Next Quiz Score: 4
New Average Score: (4+5.5)/2 = 4.75

I am wondering if there is a better way to do this? I don't want Average Scores to jump around rapidly, it should be based on how you are performing recently over a period of time (like last 5 quizzes).

Any other better ideas welcome too.
Essentially i am trying to present to him what is 'current' level of Expertise is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proposed method gives too much weight to the most recent test.  If you want each test (of the most recent 5) to have the same weight the formula you want is:

$$New\;Average=\frac{4(Old\; Average) + New\; Score}{5}$$

In the first example you mention (old average = 3, most recent test = 8) you get 4.

Comment: To emphasize:  this feels like the result you'd get if you kept all the scores and then just took the straight average of the last five tests, but it isn't equal to that.  You can't compute that number without knowing the scores on those 5 tests (or at least the oldest score).  The formula I wrote assumes that you aren't terribly worried about how the average over the last five tests was arrived at...it simply assumes that the oldest score came in at the old average.

Comment: Thanks lulu, if you have any other ideas on how to tell user how he is performing in tests recently - do post that too. Using last 5 tests is simply one such idea.